# Meteor collection.update permisions

Tags: collections, meteor

Hi i dont understand why is this not working?

```
Notifications.update({'userId':Meteor.userId(), 'notifyUserId':notifyFriendId}, {$set: {read: 1}});
```

I have update allow method as well

```
Notifications = new Meteor.Collection('Notifications');

Notifications.allow({
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Error appear:

```
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To update a collection you can only use the document's `_id`. So you need to query for it first

```
var docid = Notifications.findOne({'userId':Meteor.userId(), 'notifyUserId':notifyFriendId});
Notifications.update({_id:docid._id}, {$set: {read: 1}});
```

This is only for code that runs on the client. On the server you can run the code as you had it.

Comment: That's weird. BTW: i solved it via Meteor.methods but was curious why this not working. Thx for answer. I will not try it now but hopefuly you are right. Marking as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update the above answer:

```
var documentIdentifiers = _.pluck(Documents.find({ param: 'yourParam'}, { fields: { _id: 1 }}).fetch(), '_id');
for (var i = 0; i < documentIdentifiers.length; i++)
  Documents.update(documentIdentifiers[i], { $do: whatever });
```

This is what you do if you need to update multiple fields. The underscore pluck method, used in tandem with a field specifier, makes sure that data isn't being trucked around unnecessarily.

All my best,

Sam

Comment: Thanks. It works in my case. I use a disconnected client